# Tablib export corrupting files

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm writing a simple code to transform csv back to xls with Tablib on python.

As I understand, Tablib does conversion for you if you import the csv.

```
import tablib
imported_data = tablib.import_set(open('DB.csv',encoding='utf8').read())
f = open('workfile.xls', 'wb')
f.write(imported_data.xls)
f.close()
```

This code handles small sample of the database, but fails at one point (~600 lines) meaning that is compiles successfully but Excel cannot open the file at that point.

I'm not sure how to proceed - is this tablib failing or does Excel fail to read encoded data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative approach, you could just ask Excel to do the conversion as follows:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

src_filename = r"c:\my_folder\my_file.csv"
name, ext = os.path.splitext(src_filename)
target_filename = name + '.xls'

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(src_filename)
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs(target_filename, FileFormat=56, ConflictResolution=2) 

excel.Application.Quit()
```

Microsoft has a list of [File formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) that you can use, where `56` is used for `xls`.

Comment: This works, **but** just changes the extension. What I have is a csv file where everything is stored in one cell per row, I want those separated in different columns. Tablib import does splitting by itself, I don't suppose your code can edit content of the file in any way.

Comment: The output file should be in true XLS format. It would look the same if you open it in Excel, but if you open it in notepad you should see the difference. The code could be modified to do what you need, I will have a quick look. Can you add a sample to your question?

Comment: Crap, file provider didn't specify the separator, so due to regional settings the CSV file didn't show correctly. I'll mark this as correct, sorry for confusion.

If anyone reads this in the future, first line of CSV file should read
`sep=,` or some other delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

this two functions allow you to import from csv, after export to excel file

```
import csv 
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
import operator
# This function for import from csv 
def CSV2list_dict(file_name):
     with open(file_name) as f:
        a = [{k: int(v) for k, v in row.items()}
        for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
     return a

# file_name must be end with .xlsx
# The second parameter represente the header row of data in excel,
# The type of header is a list of string, 
# The third paramater represente the data in list dictionaries form
# The last paramater represente the order of the key 
def Export2excel(file_name, header_row, list_dict, order_by):
    list_dict.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(order_by))
    wb=Workbook(file_name)
    ws=wb.add_worksheet("New Sheet") #or leave it blank, default name is "Sheet 1"
    first_row=0
    for header in header_row:
         col=header_row.index(header) # we are keeping order.
         ws.write(first_row,col,header) # we have written first row which is the header of worksheet also.
    row=1
    for art in list_dict:
        for _key,_value in art.items():
            col=header_row.index(_key)
            ws.write(row,col,_value)
        row+=1 #enter the next row
    wb.close()

csv_data = CSV2list_dict('DB.csv')
header = ['col0','col1','col2']
order = 'col0' # the type of col0 is int
Export2excel('workfile.xlsx', header, csv_data, order)
```

Comment: I changed `open(file_name)` to `open(file_name,encoding='utf8)` to get it to properly read my file, but now I'm greeted with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'VALČIUKAS'`. I'm assuming it reads a string as a number?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new openpyxl 2.5 this will not work.  You need to remove 2.5 and instead pip install 2.4.9.

```
    import tablib
```

Depending on whether it is a dataset(one page) or databook(multiple) you need to declare:(changes here)

```
    imported_data = tablib.Dataset()
```

or

```
    imported_data = tablib.Databook()
```

Then you can import your data.(changes here)

```
    imported_data.csv = tablib.import_set(open('DB.csv', enconding='utf8').read())
```

without specifying the .csv in your example tablib doesn't know the format.

```
    imported_data = tablib.import_set(open('DB.csv',encoding='utf8').read())
```

then you could print to see the various options you have.

```
    print(imported_data)
    print(imported_data.csv)
    print(imported_data.xlsx)
    print(imported_data.dict)
    print(imported_data.db)
```

etc.

Then write your file.(No changes here)

```
    f = open('workfile.xls', 'wb')
    f.write(imported_data.xls)  # or .xlsx
    f.close()
```